# Add Subprotocol to websocket (c#, Universal App)

Tags: c#, websocket, protocols

I am trying to create a messagewebsocket with a specific sub-protocol. In javascript this wouldn't be a problem, but in c# there is no parameter for this. The only thing I've found is how to get a list of the protocols, (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocketcontrol.supportedprotocols) but there is no setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to add the name to the list:

```
   var protocollist = messageWebSocket.Control.SupportedProtocols;
   protocollist.Add("subprotocol");
```